# Voxel Animation

Tags: xna

I have been able to convert a 3D mesh from Maya into Voxel art (looks like a bunch of cubes--similar to legos), all done in Maya.  I plan on using the 3D art to wrap around my 2D textures to make it 2.5D.  My question is: does the mesh being voxelized allow me to use the pieces as particles that i can put into a particle engine in XNA to have awesome dynamic effects?

Answer (score 0):

No, because you get a set of vertices and index defining triangles with no information about cubes.

But you can create an algorithm that extract the info from the model. It's a bit hard but it's feasible.

I'd do it creating a 3d grid, and foreach face I'd launch rays from that face to the opposite face, taking every collision with the mesh, getting for each  ray a number of collisions that should be pair (0, 2, 4,...), this between two points should have a solid volume.

That way it can be converted to voxels... on each collision it would be useful to store the bones that are related to the triangle that collides, this way you would be able to animate the voxel model.

Comment: Wow, that sounds REALLY expensive.  I'm trying to make a 2.5D game with the enemies made from Voxel art that get killed much like how programs on Tron: Legacy did...i want them to fall apart as each individual cubes, but not at the expense of anything over 1/60th of a second. Is that possible?

Comment: and it is but you only have to execute the algorithm at load time, to extract info and convert it to voxels. Or you can make a tool to extract the info and save it ina format that can  be loaded faster when you run the game...